# Passing IHttpClientFactory into class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

If I have a controller class, and I want to pass it to a different namespace that handles my HTTP calls, such as in the below scenario, Main task calls TaskA() which calls TaskG(), do I need to pass it to TaskG via A like the below? Or is there someway to just create it in the namespace `HttpClassFurtherDown` without the calling classes needing to pass it.

```
namespace Controllers{
public class Drawings : ControllerBase
{
    private IHttpClientFactory _client {get;set;}
    public Drawings(IHttpClientFactory client)
    {
        _client=client;
    }

    [Route("api/Drawings")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody] JsonFileContent[] content)
    {
        HttpExample e = new HttpExample(_client);
        e.TaskA();
        TaskB();
        return Accepted($"Drawings/Job/{id}");
    }
}}

namespace HttpClassExample{
public class HttpExample
{
  private IHttpClientFactory _client {get;set;}
    public HttpExample(IHttpClientFactory client)
    {
        _client=client;
    }
    public void TaskA()
    {
        DoSomeProcessing();
        HttpClassExampleFurtherDown e = new HttpClassExampleFurtherDown(client);
        e.TaskG();
    }
}

}
namespace HttpClassExampleFurtherDown{
public class HttpExampleFurtherDown
{
  private IHttpClientFactory _client {get;set;}
    public HttpExampleFurtherDown(IHttpClientFactory client)
    {
        _client=client;
    }
    public void TaskG(client)
    {
        //Finally Using It Here. I want to avoid having to generate it at the controller level and pass it all the way down.
        client.CreateClient();
        client.SendAsync();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you newing `HttpClassExampleFurtherDown` rather than injecting it?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to avoid having to generate it at the controller level and pass it all the way down.

If following DIP then inject explicit dependencies where they are actually needed instead of tightly coupling to implementation concerns.

While I believe the example provided are oversimplified, here is what the example above should look like

*Controllers.Drawings*

```
namespace Controllers{
    using HttpClassExample;
    //...

    public class Drawings : ControllerBase {
        private readonly IHttpExample client;
        public Drawings(IHttpExample client) {
            this.client = client;
        }

        [Route("api/Drawings")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody] JsonFileContent[] content) {
            await client.TaskA();
            TaskB();
            return Accepted($"Drawings/Job/{id}");
        }
    }
}
```

*HttpClassExample.HttpExample*

```
namespace HttpClassExample{
    using HttpClassExampleFurtherDown;
    //...
    
    public class HttpExample : IHttpExample{
        private readonly IHttpExampleFurtherDown client;
        
        public HttpExample(IHttpExampleFurtherDown client) {
            this.client = client;
        }
        
        public async Task TaskA() {
            DoSomeProcessing();
            await client.TaskG();
        }
        
        //...
    }
}
```

*HttpClassExampleFurtherDown.HttpExampleFurtherDown*

```
namespace HttpClassExampleFurtherDown{
    public class HttpExampleFurtherDown : IHttpExampleFurtherDown {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory factory;
        
        public HttpExampleFurtherDown(IHttpClientFactory factory) {
            this.factory = factory;
        }
        
        public async Task TaskG() {
            HttpClient client = factory.CreateClient();
            
            //...
            
            var response = await client.SendAsync();
            
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that a container is being used to manage the resolution and injection of dependency implementations based on their registered abstractions